# Odd NS lookup, but server records look fine

Tags: domain-name-system

Not sure what happened, but something seems to have gone awry with my dns.

http://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/elitecodersllc.com

Is returning this:

```
pleasedropthishost14819.elitecodersllc.biz.
pleasedropthishost14818.elitecodersllc.biz.
```

Did a whois on elitecodersllc.biz and it shows it as not being registered.  I'm no DNS expert for sure.  Could it somehow have been hijacked or something?  I've checked the DNS entries on the server and they all look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not registered. Have you forgot to renew the domain? Better check with your domain provider ASAP, before it's gone.

BTW, the server entries might look good, but if the domain isn't registered, that doesn't matter.

Comment: elitecodersllc.biz is not mine.  think I may have found the issue at the registrar.

Answer (score 1):

I can't resolve ns1.elitecodersllc.com or ns2.elitecodersllc.com (and neither can most of the rest of the net according to that DNS tester site).  Are the "[glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)" configured correctly at the domain registrar?  The registrar needs to know the IP addresses of your dns servers since nobody can ask ns1.elitecodersllc.com about the address of ns1.elitecodersllc.com.

If you *just* changed hosting, then the odd results are probably due to caching of the old records, and one of them points to a note left by the admin of your previous host to remove the account.

Comment: That is actually what I'm trying to do ... move my hosting to a new provider.  So ideally what I want to do is get the dns moved to the new server and changed to reference the new server.  Maybe it would be better to have the dns hosted on an entirely different machine or service?